# How to handle DLL dependencies between .NET dll and non-.NET dll's

Tags: .netlink

I think my problem arises because I am successful with loading a .NET assembly, creating an instance and calling methods from a .NET dll.  Certain methods, however, call methods from other non.NET dlls.  Those methods are not exposed via the sdk I am working with. Here's an example:

```
    Needs["NETLink`"]
    InstallNET[];
    OL490Assembly = LoadNETAssembly["OL490SDKDll.dll"]
    OLLibSDK = NETNew["OL490_SDK_Dll.OL490SdkLibrary"]
```

This method seems to work:
        OLLibSDK@GetOL490SerialNumber[]
Returns: "NoOL490Found"
which is correct since I'm currently not connected to the device.

However, when I call
        OLLibSDK@ConnectToOL490[0]

I get the following:

NET::netexcptn: "A .NET exception occurred: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CyLibCpp, Version=1.0.3636.28588, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.\nFile name: 'CyLibCpp, Version=1.0.3636.28588, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'\ n   at OL490Lib.CmdLib..ctor(Int32 dIndex)\ n   at OL490_SDK _Dll.OL490SdkLibrary.ConnectToOL490(Int64 dOL490Index)\ n \ nWRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.\nTo enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM \ Software \ Microsoft \ Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.\ nNote: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.\nTo turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM \ Software \ Microsoft \ Fusion!EnableLog]."

It is trying to access CyLibCpp.dll.  If I try to load this as a .NET assembly, I get

"A .NET exception occurred: "System.BadImageFormatException: Could \
not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\ WINDOWS \ assembly \ GAC \ \
OL490 \ CyLibCpp.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was \
made to load a program with an incorrect format."

This implies to me that CyLibCpp.dll is not a .NET dll.

Has anyone run into these types of dependency issues and found a resolution?

Thanks